# breaking out of two loops in c++

Tags: c++, loops, class, break

I have written this function that takes string as argument and compares with the class member variable ID which is a character array. For some reason, it's not reading the specific object although I think i have got the conditions and break statements correct. If the the two ID's match, the show function is to be called and it's supposed to break out of the fall loop, match the check condition and then break out of the while loop. If at any index, the two do not match, it instantly breaks out of the for loop and then the while loop and exits the function. Where am i going wrong?

```
  void readspecificitem(string id)
  {
    ifstream fp; 
    Item e; 
    fp.open("Hello.dat",ios::in| ios::binary);
    bool check=false; 
    while(1)
    {
        if(fp.eof())
        { 
            break;
        }
        fp.read((char*) &e, sizeof(e));
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if(e.ID[i]!=id[i]) 
            { 
                check=true;
                break;
            } 
            if(i=2)
            { 
                e.show();
                check=true; 
            }
        }
        if (check==true)
        break; 
    }
    fp.close(); 
}
  void show()
{
    cout << "Item ID: " ; 
    for(char c : ID)
        cout << c;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Name: "; 
    for(char c : name)
        cout << c;
    cout << endl;
    cout<< "Stock: " << stock  <<endl;
    cout<< "Cost per unit: " << cost << endl; 
}
```

Comment: `if(i=2)` -> `if(i==2)`. Turn on your compiler warnings, and read what they say, it'll save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: you must have got a warning on that line

Comment: `if(fp.eof())` may lead to trouble. eof is only set to true when you attempt to read past the end of the file.

Comment: `while (!check)` is an easy fix here. No need to `break`. You can also do `if (check)` instead of `if (check == true)` because what else would a boolean be if not true?

Comment: `Item` I hope this is a POD type and thus does not contain a `std::string`

Comment: There are better solutions here, but when I have nested loops with an early exit, I use a function. You can return from the function any time you want to get out.

Comment: To break out of both loops here you can just `return;`. The file will be closed automatically when it goes out of scope.